# Unable to execute Python script on web server

Tags: python, webserver, cgi

I have the following HTML file located in the `/test` folder of my website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <h1>Enter the texts to be compared</h1>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/test_python.cgi" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text1">
    <input type="text" name="text2">
    <input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Check !">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this Python script located in the `/cgi-bin` folder of my website:

```
#!/usr/bin/python   
print('Content-type: text/html\r\n\r')
```

I am able to access the HTML file using a web browser, but pressing the "Check!" button results in a 404 message. The CGI file has 755 execute permissions assigned to it.

This is shared hosting, so I don't know for sure what features are installed or not. But CGI should at least work. I am new to Python. Is there a way to get this setup to work? Thanks.

Comment: What is your python file named?

Comment: It is named `test_python.cgi`.

Comment: If it matters, I am unable to navigate to `/usr/bin/python` using FTP. It says there is no such file or directory. There appears to be a shortcut or something to a folder `/usr/bin/python2`, but when I try to go there the FTP program instead downloads a 8KB binary file named `python2`.

Comment: Locate the `httpd.conf` for your site and post the contents here.

Comment: Its a shared hosting, so you don't have access to httpd.conf, but you might have a .htaccess file (or you can create one). But you are getting 404 error, which happens when some file is not where it is supposed to be. Try going to www.yoursite.com/cgi-bin/test-python.cgi directly, and see if you still get the 404 error.

Comment: Thanks. I tried linking to the CGI file directly, but still get a 404 message. I also have `.htaccess` files in other directories, but not in `cgi-bin`. And if I move `test_python.cgi` to another directory, the browser will try to download it instead of executing it.

Comment: You only need a single .htaccess file, and that in your index folder (/somepath/public_html/ .. or something similar). And as you figured, your cgi files will only execute in cgi-bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the cgi-folder itself (not talking about python cgi file) has 755 permissions as well. I think that is the problem here.

Also, try running a sample perl cgi Hello World file: 
https://practicalperl5.blogspot.com/2014/02/hello-world.html

Comment: The folder is 755 as well. There are a few files already in it, but I don't know what they are for.

Comment: The files are: `cgiecho`, `cgiemail`, `entropybanner.cgi`, `randhtml.cgi`. They appear to be compiled.

Comment: It seems, it is better to contact your Host, via email or phone. Sometimes some Admins, disable CGI until explicitly requested, or change the config away from default values.